# how to pass values of submitted form element in php

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I am using this custom code, which works great, to extract information of a Wordpress table:

```
$post_ids = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id FROM wp_posts");
foreach ( $post_ids as $ids ) 
{
    echo "<form action='make.php' method='post'>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='" . $ids->id . "'><input type='submit' name='id'>";
    echo "</form>";
}
```

at the very top of the same php file I have this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
        echo $ids->id;
}
```

My question is: how do I pass the unique id of a submitted text field to the
-if- statement at the top of the page? Eventually I would like to use it in order to update the Wordpress table.

Comment: But the scope of $_POST is global. You can check it anywhere in your script...

Comment: `<input type='text' name='unique_id' value='" . $ids->id . "'>` then access with `$_POST['unique_id']`?

Comment: when I click the submit button the page refreshes, yet no result on the echo (for testing).

Comment: I've changed it to $_POST['unique_id'] ... yet no result.

Comment: Do you wish to have individual forms for each postID or you want one form and several postIDs?

Comment: I want to have one form with several postIDs ... each row has a unique id and when submitted I want to pass one or more inputs to the if statement.

Comment: Then your code needs to be adjusted. Will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the way your code is written, you are creating a new form each time through the loop for each post id.
That needs to change, by moving the opening and closing `<form ...></form>` tag as well as the submit button 
outside of the loop.

Secondly, there's no way your make.php file gets the `$ids->id` variable (remember HTTP is a stateless protocol)
unless you let it know it is available using one of PHP's super global arrays, in this case the `$_POST` super-global
array.

With the above points taken into account, a re-written version of your code is presented below:

```
$post_ids = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id FROM wp_posts");

echo "<form action='make.php' method='post'>";

foreach ( $post_ids as $ids ) 
{
   echo "<input type='text' name='". $ids->id. "' value='". $ids->id. "'><br>";
}

echo "<input type='submit' name='id'>";
echo "</form>";
```

then inside your 'make.php' file:

```
if(isset($_POST['id']))
{

   foreach($_POST AS $key => $value)
   {
      if($key != 'id') //make sure we don't include the submit button in our processing
      {
         $unique_post_id = trim($value);
         echo $unique_post_id. '<br>';
         //do something with $unique_post_id
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! got it ... my bad ;-)
There is an issue ... the id name of the text input should be $ids->id and not $curr_post_id. This is the value that I need to pass to the make.php file.

It can be either one value or more that will be change and submitted.

Comment: Well, if it answered your question, you could specify it as the accepted answer.

Comment: your answer is great, but it's only part of the solution, as mentioned in my previous reply.

Comment: so, are you still having any issues?

Comment: yes. I've changed my code to match yours.
all is taking place in one file: make.php (the form and also the if statement).

I am trying to echo $current_id and I guess because the page refreshes I get not result.

Comment: what is the issue you are having? can you be explicit about it?

Comment: take a look at my previous reply.

Comment: Updated my answer to take into account your reply.

Comment: Thanks again. How do I echo the results? Please remember that the form and the --if-- statement are written in the same php file (make.php).

Comment: juse use `echo $unique_id`. Updated the answer to take that into account, too. Bur you should seriously upgrade your PHP and general programming knowledge.

Comment: THANKS - it works!!! I am aware to the lack of knowledge ... this is why I am asking and learning from people like you ;-)